# Magento 2.3 - Customer Firstname in Email

Tags: magento2.3, transactional-mail

How can we load the customer first name in transactional emails in Magento 2.3?

We tried this, but that does not work;

```
{{trans "%name," name=$order.getBillingAddress().getFirstName()}}
```

Comment: try getFirstname

Comment: try {{var order.getCustomerFirstname()}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can use getCustomerFirstname().

```
{{trans "Hi %first_name," first_name=$order.getCustomerFirstname()}}
```